# F# Function composition with two parameter function

Tags: f#

I thought I understood function composition until I looked at the example in Microsoft's help. It show the following example:

```
let appendString (string1:string) (string2:string) = string1 + string2
let appendExtension fileExtension = appendString "." >> appendString fileExtension
let fileName = appendExtension "myfile" "txt"
```

The type of `appendExtension` is `string -> (string -> string)`. This seems right since it is a partial application. But the missing parameter is the first one not the second. How is this possible?

If I were to write `appendExtension` without composition I would do :

```
let appendExtension name extension = appendString (appendString name ".") extension
```

The code in the parentheses looks like the first part the of the composition but it is a full application of `appendString`.<
So we remove one of the parameters to make a partial application and thus a function. 
But the first parameter was removed not the second. 
How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fileExtension` parameter in `appendExtension` is **missnamed** - it is indeed the `filename`! But of course this does not really matter here as names only really matter to the programmer.

If in doubt dismantle the *offending* expression step by step:

```
appendExtension "myfile" "txt" =
(appendExtension "myfile") "txt" =
// definition of appendExtension - insert "myfile" into `fileExtension` ..
(appendString "." >> appendString "myfile") "txt" =
// expand ">>" into "|>" IMHO easiest
"txt" |> appString "." |> appendString "myfile" =
// insert in first
appString "." "txt" |> appendString "myfile" =
// apply first
".txt" |> appendString "myfile" =
// insert and apply second
"myfile.txt"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Doing it step-by-step is a good way to figure it out. This gos show the power of names. It was the bad name that got me thinking in the wrong direction. So I now see that the extra parameter "txt" gets added to the left function and then this result gets added to the right function. Sounds strait forward now that you have explained it!

Comment: If this helped you than please mark it as an answer - of course you can wait for more answers if you like

Answer (score 1):

Using the simplest understanding of composition, namely:

```
(f >> g) x = g(f(x))
```

we have

```
let appendExtension s = appendString "." >> appendString s

appendExtension "myfile" "txt"
=> (appendString "." >> appendString "myfile") "txt"
=> appendString "myfile" (appendString "." "txt")
=> appendString "myfile" (".txt")
=> "myfile.txt"
```

which was already explained by Carsten.

You bring up some great points in your question around *partial application*, and I would agree with you that the example is perhaps a terrible one, or least a horribly confusing one.  When I think of partial application, I would expect (and maybe I'm the only one who feels this way), that

```
appendExtension ext
```

would product a function that added the extension `ext` to a string!  If this were the case, I could say:

```
let addTxt = appendExtension "txt"
```

so

```
addTxt "myfile"
=> "myfile.txt"
```

Similarly,

```
appendString s
```

should produce the function that added `s` to its argument.  Under this view of the world, which I prefer, but probably no one else does, we have this derivation:

```
(appendExtension "txt") "myfile"
=> (appendString "." >> appendString "txt") "myfile"
=> appendString "txt" (appendString "." "myfile")
=> appendString "txt" ("myfile.")
=> "myfile.txt"
```

Either way works, I suppose.  I like my way because partial application just makes more sense.  So how to we rationalize the confusing Microsoft example?  The idea is that when they write:

```
appendString s
```

they mean this is a function that **appends something to s**, NOT that function that appends `s` to something.  IMHO this is a terrible and confusing way to read English.  They expect

```
appendString "dog"
```

to mean the function that appends to "dog", but it looks the function that appends "dog".  Why did they do this?  Maybe they wanted

```
appendString "dog" "house"
```

to read like it was appending from left to right.  They wanted to make it look like a two-argument function.  Ewwww.  Perhaps that is the convention, but it is one to try to be aware of when thinking of partial application.